# How can I set up the logging context from middleware?

Tags: http, go, gorilla

I want to populate the logging context by items in the request, for example: `r.Header.Get("X-Request-Id")`. I assumed I could override the Log type in the handler from middleware. Though it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/apex/log"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Assumption: handler is the shared state between the functions
type handler struct{ Log *log.Entry }

// New creates a handler for this application to co-ordinate shared resources
func New() (h handler) { return handler{Log: log.WithFields(log.Fields{"test": "FAIL"})} }

func (h handler) index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.Log.Info("Hello from the logger")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "YO")
}

func main() {
    h := New()

    app := mux.NewRouter()
    app.HandleFunc("/", h.index)
    app.Use(h.loggingMiddleware)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), app); err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("error listening")
    }

}

func (h handler) loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.Log = log.WithFields(log.Fields{"test": "PASS"})
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Can you see why `h.Log = log.WithFields(log.Fields{"test": "PASS"})` doesn't seem to have any effect on `h.Log.Info("Hello from the logger")` which should be IIUC within the same request?

Comment: A minimal example works: https://play.golang.org/p/vHgCYZpaELw but how come it doesn't work from within the middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your logger to be request-scoped. You're setting it globally for the entire handler, every time a new connection comes in, which means you're asking for data races, and generally undesirable behavior.

For request-scoped context, the [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) embedded in the request is perfect. You can access it through the [`Context()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) and [`WithContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext) methods.

Example:

```
var loggerKey = "Some unique key"

func (h handler) loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, loggerKey, log.WithFields(log.Fields{"test": "PASS"}))
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx)
    })
}
```

Then to access your logger:

```
func doSomething(r *http.Request) error {
    log, ok := r.Context().Value(loggerKey).(*log.Logger) // Or whatever type is appropriate
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("logger not set on context!")
    }
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Can't get it to work https://play.golang.org/p/KkEWiJfvYI6 ... also I ideally want to avoid context setup on every handler.

Comment: What do you mean "avoid context setup on every handler"?

Comment: I'm assuming I need to do a `log, ok := r.Context().Value(loggerKey).(*log.Logger)` in every handler? Any ideas why https://play.golang.org/p/KkEWiJfvYI6 doesn't work for me?

Comment: You need to do that (or an equivalent function) in every logger, yes. But that isn't context setup. That's just getting the previously-setup logger from the context.

Comment: Noticed https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation which has confused me further with context. Just thought I'd mention it. Still puzzled what I am doing wrong here: https://play.golang.org/p/KkEWiJfvYI6

Comment: I think I finally understand! http://play.golang.org/p/iPwgckXEscs Thank you again

Comment: How to access the logger once the next.ServeHttp() is finished, cause the handler function might add additional fields once it finishes the processing, for example Errors etc could be added later on.