# Why does sharing state via Context only work with my request middleware?

Tags: go, struct, mux

I've been [struggling with sharing state from some middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983638).

Previously in Golang I've setup a "handler struct" and used functions of the definition `func (h handler) doSomething` to share that information in that struct. This paradigm has served me well, except it doesn't work in mux request middleware.

```
  func (h handler) loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
          logging := log.WithFields(log.Fields{"requestID": r.Header.Get("X-Request-Id")})
          h.Log = logging
          next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
      })
  }
```

However using **[Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context)** does.

```
  func (h handler) loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
          logging := log.WithFields(log.Fields{"requestID": r.Header.Get("X-Request-Id")})
          ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), logger, logging)
          next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
      })
  }
```

Full code can be found upon https://github.com/kaihendry/apex-request-id

**Why** though? Have I incorrectly been using this *handler* approach to sharing state, and I should be using **context** instead? Why doesn't the *handler* "request scoped"? (not sure on the terminologies here)

Comment: 1.) You're setting `h.Log` on a non-pointer receiver, which means that `h` is a copy visible only to the scope of the surrounding func. 2.) Even if you make `h` a pointer still it is not clear what `next`'s implementation is nor what it's data is, therefore we don't know if it's the same instance as `h` or whether it holds a reference to `h`, if it's the case that none of the  two are true then `next` has no knowledge of `h` nor `h.Log`.

Comment: ... looking at the code in your repo you probably need to satisfy only point 1.) from the previous comment. Change the handler method definitions like so: from `func (h handler) ...` to `func (h *handler) ...`

Comment: Whoa thanks! How can I NOT make this same mistake again?

Comment: In case that's not a rhetorical question: You just need to remember that if a method wants to modify the state of its receiver that receiver must be a pointer. It's a fairly simple rule and shouldn't be too hard to remember.

Comment: in the showversion handler, it doesn't appear to work unless I make it a pointer receiver, even though it does not modify the *Log.entry IIUC https://s.natalian.org/2019-01-03/pointer-receiver.mp4

Comment: That's because you're passing showversion as a *method value*. Quoting from the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) *"The method value x.M is a function value that is callable with the same arguments as a method call of x.M. **The expression x is evaluated and saved during the evaluation of the method value; the saved copy is then used as the receiver in any calls**, which may be executed later."* Basically `h` of showversion doesn't see the changes made by logginMiddleware because it's a copy created before loggingMiddleware was ever called.

Comment: It is recommended practice that the methods in a method set be defined on the same kind of receiver, ie either all on a non-pointer or all on a pointer receiver. This is just a recommendation but it avoids headaches like this.

Comment: ok, so all my http handlers should switch to (h *handler) style. ok.. lots of code to update. Thank you again!

Comment: You are using one instance of `handler` to handle all requests - if you make it a pointer receiver, things will only get worst. You should use simple functions.

Comment: Ok, if I make all on a non-pointer receiver, e.g. (h handler) iiuc, then setting h.Log from the middleware would never work right?

Comment: Be great if you could please review what I've done here: https://youtu.be/yvQecP-8uJ8